# Why does a variable random function need to be created inside a loop to work correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal was to create a variable with a random function where the variable changes for each loop it runs through.

I created the variable `age` with the random function. When I run it through multiple loops, instead of giving me multiple random numbers, it only gave me one random number and looped that over.

I've solved this issue, but I want to understand why it was necessary to create the variable with the random function within the for loop in order for it to work.

```py
import random

people = ['eddie', 'irina', 'eric']

random.shuffle(people)

age = random.randrange(1, 120)

for person in people:
    print(person.title() + " is " + str(age) + " years old.)

>>Irina is 32 years old.
>>Eric is 32 years old. 
>>Eddie is 32 years old.
```

---

```py
import random

people = ['eddie', 'irina', 'eric']

random.shuffle(people)

for person in people:

    age = random.randrange(1, 120)

    print(person.title() + " is " + str(age) + " years old.)

>>Irina is 24 years old.
>>Eric is 10 years old. 
>>Eddie is 80 years old.
```

Comment: You get a single result from a single call to `randrange()`. You want a different number you need to call it again. `age` is just a number; it’s not going change each time you look t it.

Comment: In the first case you set `age` to a random number and use it in all the loop's iterations. In the second case you set `age` to a new random number on each iteration...

Answer (score 0):

As you intially defined `age` outside of the loop, the variable `age` is assigned the VALUE which is returned by the random function. As you don't redefine its value at every iteration of the loop, its value will remain constant, hence why it looped with the same value.

However, once the statement is inside the `for` loop, the variable is assigned to the (new) value of the random function every time the loop iterates, meaning that the variable's value changed at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first snippet, you are creating a random number one time, then printing the same random number multiple times in the loop.

In the second snippet, you are creating a random number with every iteration of the loop, thus making it (most likely) unique every time.

Think of the first scenario as this:

1. Rolling a die
2. Saying "It's (number)!"
3. Saying "It's (number)!"
4. Saying "It's (number)!"

The second scenario would be this:

1. Rolling a die
2. Saying "It's (number)!"
3. Rerolling a die
4. Saying "It's (number)!"
5. Rerolling a die
6. Saying "It's (number)!"

You must use this second approach to get a different number every time.